# Time Warping - Procrustes Canonical Time Warping Alignment stuck on first entry

Tags: time-series

Context: Working on Temporal Alignment for sign-language features.

I'm comparing three methods for time-warping (Uniform Time Warping - UTW, Procrustes Dynamical Time Warping - PDTW, Procrustes Canonical Time Warping - PCTW) on some and get results, which are hard to explain for myself. I expected the PDTW and PDTW to be at least somewhat comparable, but in the results are vastly different. This is mainly, because the PCTW gets stuck on the first entry: [image: alignments for two exemplary samples, samples 3 and 5, each with the three respective time-warping alignments]

Now I looked into it in some more detail, occasionaly it also might get stuck on another index later on, but only rarely, and comparably a lot shorter. I can upload graphs of that as well if needed.
I use the MATLAB implementation by Zhou and De la Torre based on [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26761734).

I'm really grateful for any idea how to interprete and possibly fix this.